# How to get a Ubuntu Host on the network

Tags: networking

I have a machine with a new Ubuntu Linux installed and can't access the network.  There is a light beside the Ethernet cable but when I try to access a web address, I get the message "unable to resolve ... " When I ping a known address I get the message "ping: connect: Network is unreachable"

I can ping 127.0.0.1 successfully.  The version is Ubuntu Linux 20.04.3 LTS  I edited the "/etc/network/interfaces" file to read auto enp0s25; iface enp0s25 inet static; address 192.165.216.69; netmask 255.255.255.0; gateway 192.168.216.1; dns-nameservers 192.168.216.1; nameservers 75.75.75.75

If I go tothe "files" activity and choose "Other locations" from the window that appears and click on "Windows Network" I get a message "Failed to retrieve share list from server. No such file or directory"

Back in the Windows world I learned that the OS want to be in control.  Attempts to usurp that most often end up with the OS refusing to play.  Past experience taken to heart I finally reloaded Ubuntu from the previous mem stick.  This reformatted the HD before reinstalling Ubuntuand now everything works as it should.  No answer but PROBLEM SOLVED

Comment: From your `ip a` output I see that your machine has no IP address assigned neither on Ethernet (`enp0s25`) nor Wi-Fi (`wlp2s1`) interface. How is your network organized? Is there a DHCP server (for example a router) that assigns addresses? If not, you must configure the IP address manually. For this you need to know what address range is in your network.

Comment: Look at the network logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: Thank you !!  There is a DHCP server on the network but for some reason an IP address isn't being assigned.  Looking at the network log(s) using the above command, the output is 129 lines which tells me that the DHCP request timed out.  Don't know yet why this is.

Comment: I also tried pinging 127.0.0.1 which returned 100%  I'll work on setting a static IP address at least on a temporary basis and report back.  Again much thanks to everyone.

Comment: Ive run into a permissions issue when trying to edit the /etc/network/interfaces file in order to set a static address.  I'll need to untangle that.

Comment: Having solved permissions, Ive edited the /etc/network/interfaces file to look like the following:   auto eth0; iface eth0; inet static; address 192.168.216.69; netmask 255.255.255.255; gateway 192.168.216.1; dns-nameservers 192.168.216.1; dns-nameservers 75.75.75.75

Comment: After restarting the Linux machine and pinging either of the name servers, I get the message "Network is unreachable"  If I ping 127.0.0.1 i get all of the packets returned. Suggestions ??

Comment: What release Ubuntu are you running and is this a desktop or server?  "interfaces" hasn't been used for awhile, at least from my desktops and running the GNOME network setup.