# unable to access a network on a Ubuntu machine

Tags: networking

I have Ubuntu version 20.04.3 installed on a machine but cannot cannot access my home network.  The machine is attached with a wire and the light is on next to the Ethernet connector.  I have a windows machine on a desk connected with a wire to the same network which is attached.

I ran the command "ip a" from the terminal window on the Ubuntu Linux machine and got the following response:

```
bill@bill-Vostro-200:~$ ip a
1:  lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
     link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
     inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
     inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_code1 state UP group default glen 1000
    link/ether 00:id:09:95:fb:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:9c:af:dc:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
bill@bill-Vostro-200:~$

I gave up and reinstalled Ubuntu from the original Memory stick.  Able to access the network.  PROBLEM SOLVED
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a Ubuntu Host on the network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400607/how-to-get-a-ubuntu-host-on-the-network)

Comment: you don't have an IP address... so you either didn't configure the wired interface or whatever you did to configure it(dhcp maybe?) did not work. Either way, that is the end result you want, is an IP address for enp0s25.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetworkManager to check the connection status and also if you need to bring up a interface or to read a new config file from networks.

- To list all connection availables run `nmcli con show`. Check for your ethernet network name.
- Then restart the ethernet interface with `nmcli con down "network-name"` and then `nmcli con up "network-name"`

This should bring the interface up without restarting the network service.

NOTE

- if you want more information of your connection configuration use `nmcli con show <"network-name">`

Comment: Hello. Please read the question. This has noting to do with the question that was asked.

Comment: Hello @David. It just a method to restart the network interface. Most of the time network issues could be resolve by restarting the network interface or forcing the system to read the configuration file. Thanks.